# I composed sending bitmap using C

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, bitmap, winsock

In before question I know I don't check sent bytes and received bytes.
So I add code checking receiving bytes and sending bytes. but server can't print bitmap.

I do debug in VS2017(F11), I check sent bytes = 3368304(send function returns 3368304 = n), received bytes = 3368304(recv function returns 3368304 = n)

Both values are same. This means all data is sent to server, and all data is received from client.

But, server does not print client's bitmap.

server code.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hdcWindow;
    static HDC hdcbuffer;
    static HBITMAP hbm = NULL;
    static BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    static WSADATA wsadata;
    static SOCKET s, cs;
    static SOCKADDR_IN addr = { 0 }, c_addr;
    static int size = sizeof(c_addr);
    static char* buffer;
    static int length = 0;
    static int n = 0;
    static int count = 0;

    switch (iMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hdcWindow = GetDC(hwnd);
        hdcbuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata);
        s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(9190);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        bind(s, (LPSOCKADDR)&addr, sizeof(addr));

        WSAAsyncSelect(s, hwnd, WM_ASYNC, FD_ACCEPT);

        listen(s, 5) == -1;
        break;
    case WM_ASYNC:
        switch (lParam)
        {
        case FD_ACCEPT:
            size = sizeof(c_addr);
            cs = accept(s, (LPSOCKADDR)&c_addr, &size);
            recv(cs, (char*)&bi, sizeof(bi), 0);

            WSAAsyncSelect(cs, hwnd, WM_ASYNC, FD_READ);
            break;
        case FD_READ:
            buffer = (char*)malloc(bi.biSizeImage);
            
            length = bi.biSizeImage;
            while (count < length)
            {
                n = recv(cs, buffer + count, length, 0);

                if (n == -1)
                    break;

                count += n;
                length -= n;
            }

            hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, bi.biWidth, bi.biHeight);

            SelectObject(hdcbuffer, hbm);

            SetDIBits(hdcbuffer, hbm, 0, bi.biHeight, buffer, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

            BitBlt(hdcWindow, 0, 0, bi.biWidth, bi.biHeight, hdcbuffer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            free(buffer);
            DeleteObject(hbm);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcWindow);
            DeleteDC(hdcbuffer);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        closesocket(cs);
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

client code.

```
HINSTANCE hinst;
char* lpbitmap = NULL;
SOCKET s;
RECT rcClient;
HDC hdcScreen;
HDC hdcWindow;
SOCKADDR_IN addr;

int CaptureAnImage(HWND hWnd)
{
    static HDC hdcMemDC;
    static HBITMAP hbmScreen;
    static BITMAP bmpScreen;
    static int count = 0;
    static int n = 0;
    static int length = 0;

    hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    SetStretchBltMode(hdcWindow, HALFTONE);

    StretchBlt(hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,
        hdcScreen,
        0, 0,
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
        SRCCOPY);

    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom
        - rcClient.top);

    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    BitBlt(hdcMemDC,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
        hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        SRCCOPY);

    GetObject(hbmScreen, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0, bmpScreen.bmHeight, NULL, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    if (!bi.biSizeImage)
    {
        bi.biSizeImage = (((bi.biWidth*bi.biBitCount + 0x1F)&~0x1F) >> 3)*bi.biHeight;
    }


    lpbitmap = (char*)malloc(bi.biSizeImage);

    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    send(s, (char*)&bi, sizeof(bi), 0);
    
    length = bi.biSizeImage
    while (count < length) {
        n = send(s, lpbitmap + count, length, 0);
        if (n == -1) {
            break;
        }
        count += n;
        length -= n;
    }
    
    free(lpbitmap);
    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We don't need to see a client-server application. One side is enough (either the server writing the bitmap to disk, or the client reading the binary data from disk). Splitting the program in two helps identifying where the issue is.

Comment: Did you check that the blob (binary large object) built in the client is actually the bitmap you want? If so, how?

Comment: What *does* the server print? Does the server print the bitmap if you make the bitmap on the server instead of receiving it?